# Storing an inherited class in a vector

Tags: c++, vector, storage, object-slicing

I have a main class of an object called CEmploye and a child of this class called CTechnicien.
This is the code for CEmploye

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class CEmploye
{
public:
    /*Constructeurs/Destructeurs*/
    CEmploye ();
    CEmploye (std::string p_nom, std::string p_prenom, int p_age, int p_anciennete);
    ~CEmploye ();

protected:
    /*Nom de l'employe*/
    std::string m_nom;
    /*Prenom de l'employe*/
    std::string m_prenom;
    /*Age de l'employe*/
    int m_age;
    /*Annee d'anciennete de l'employe*/
    int m_anciennete;
};
```

And this is the code for CTechnicien :

```
#pragma once
#include "CEmploye.h"
class CTechnicien :
    public CEmploye
{
public:
    /*Constructeur/Destructeur*/
    CTechnicien ();
    CTechnicien (int p_nbUniteProduite, std::string p_nom, std::string p_prenom, int p_age, int p_anciennete);
    ~CTechnicien ();

protected:
    /*Nombre d'unite produite par le technicien*/
    int m_nbUniteProduite;
    static float BASE;
    static float PART;
    static float
```

I created an other class to manage everything and within it a vector of CEmploye :

```
std::vector<CEmploye> m_vecteurEmploye;
```

What I'm trying to do is to store a CTechnicien in this vector. But when I do, it seems like my CTechnicien is converted into a CEmploye and that's not what I want.
So I have a method in my CPersonnel like that :

```
void CPersonnel::Embaucher (CEmploye * p_pNew)
{
    m_vecteurEmploye.push_back (*p_pNew);
    return;
}
```

And this is the bit of code that I did to store my class :

```
CPersonnel mainListe;
CTechnicien test (500, "test", "Test", 25, 0);

mainListe.Embaucher (&test);
```

So is there a way to store my CTechnicien in my vector of CEmploye whithout losing the fact that it's a CTechnicien ?

Comment: You cannot store object by value with inheritance due to slicing.

Comment: No. Even worse, your `CTechnicien` will be sliced.

Comment: You might want `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<CEmploye>>`.